# Intercept sorting the items of a JavaFX 8 TableView

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, comparable

I have an applications that hosts a `TableView`. Whenever the user sorts the rows by clicking the header of a particular column, I need to

1. Save the current order of items,
2. Do the actual sorting,
3. Save the new order of items.

I was able to spot this:

```
this.tableView.sortPolicyProperty().set(t -> {
        System.out.println("saving source order");
        ... // Saving
        FXCollections.sort(tableView.getItems(), t.getComparator());
        System.out.println("saving target order");
        ... // Saving
        return true;
});
```

However, this throws `ClassCastException` pretty often. Is there a better way of saving the item permutations before and after sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen to it using the `ListChangeListener` *the better way* :)

```
tv.getItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<T>(){
            @Override
            public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<
                                   ? extends T> c) {        
            while(c.next()){
              if(c.wasPermutated()){
                   System.out.println("is permuated");
              }
           }
       }

});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It did. Thank you! :-)